# TextBox keypress event handling for decimals for a range 0 to 9999999999.99

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a textbox keypress handler which handles a decimal input range of 0 to 9999999999.99 value. I have this code below but is not serving the purpose. With it I cannot enter decimals after 10 digits.

```
public static void NumericWithDecimalTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
        (e.KeyChar != '.'))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    string[] parts = textBox.Text.Split('.');

    // only allow one decimal point
    if (((e.KeyChar == '.') && (textBox.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)) || (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && ((parts[0].Length >= 10))))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills Sorry I have corrected the question.

Comment: @mjwills Ishould allow only 10 digits prefix to decimal.

Comment: Consider changing `10` to `13`. Then try using `double.TryParse` on `textBox.Text` and checking the result is <= `9999999999.99`.

Comment: Use a `NumericUpDown` control.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the process by having the data validated, along the lines of:

```
public static void NumericWithDecimalTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    var enteredValue = textBox.Text;
    var decimalValue = 0M;

    if (decimal.TryParse(enteredValue, out decimalValue) && ValueIsWithinRange(decimalValue, 0M, 9999999999.99M))
    {
        Model.ThePropertyStoringTheValue = decimalValue; // wherever you need to store the value
    }
    else
    {
        // Inform the user they have entered invalid data (i.e. change the textbox background colour or show a message box)
    }
}

private bool ValueIsWithinRange(decimal valueToValidate, decimal lower, decimal upper)
{
    return valueToValidate >= lower && valueToValidate <= upper
}
```

That way, if the value is valid, it is written to the model (following good MVC design practices) and if it is invalid, the user is informed with a message that would allow them to make corrections (e.g. "the value you have entered isn't a valid decimal" or "the value must not be negative" etc.)